# One Goldstone boson from breaking of two different symmetries

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, symmetry, symmetry-breaking

I am looking for examples where **only one Goldstone boson** appears after **spontaneous breaking of 2 different symmetries**.

In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/278249/) post there is an answer why there are no Goldstone bosons for rotational symmetry **on a lattice**. I am interested in examples for continuous systems.

Question is inspired by [this talk](https://youtu.be/-PhIcG5d9cg) by Sieberg, more precisely by statement around 1:19:00.

Comment: Thank you! Could you post concrete links to references?

Comment: [Manohar & Low](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.88.101602). Track citations thereto.

Comment: Might read up on Brauner, T., 2010, *Spontaneous symmetry breaking and Nambu–Goldstone bosons in quantum many-body systems*,  Symmetry, **2** (2), pp.609-657.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you! I don't get idea and exploration yet, maybe you can help me with it, I think that essence very intuitive. But, your examples about space-time symmetry, as I understand. Does it mean, that such phenomena can't occur in internal of gauge symmetry?

Comment: For fully Lorentz invariant theories and SSBroken internal symmetries, one broken generator per goldston, as you may read up in QFT books. Your question is spectacularly orthogonal to that.

Comment: @CosmasZachos What about example in Maxwell theory, when electric and magnetic two form symmetries are both broken in Coulomb phase, but Goldstone boson only one -- photon?

Comment: @CosmasZachos , I edited question

Comment: Ugh! your are really talking about NS's 1-form symmetries, not ordinary standard textbook QFT internal symmetries! He's reformulated the entire landscape. In plain Lorentz invariant QFT the goldston to broken-internal-symmetry counting still holds.

Comment: @CosmasZachos , No. Did you watch fragment of video around 1:19:00?  Exist 2 1-form symmetries, and they both are broken in Coulomb phase, but particle only one!

Comment: I can't help you. I strongly believe you are "misreading" [him](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5148). Weinberg's QFT book II, p173 & 295 reviews the standard picture for conventional scalar Noether ***independent*** symmetry charges. You may speculate with Natti on 1-form ones, and fall for his glib evasions, but that is far *beyond* the context of mainstream relativistic QFT. Condensed matter breaks Lorentz invariance; and Natti calls membrane physics "particle physics", a broad stretch. Weinberg's book, or Coleman's lectures, the "owners" of the field. –